# Powershell / Winforms position of multiple forms

Tags: winforms, powershell

So i created a power shell script with a win form GUI. Due to bad decisions i cannot resize it without breaking the layout.

From within the main form i start 1 or two "child" forms. Is there a way i can make them "stick" together?
Like magnetize the windows? I know how to give them positions, but i like them to always stick together regardless of resolution or position of main form.

Right now i can only come up with:

```
$MainForm.StartPosition = "manual"
$MainForm.Location = "25,30"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really think you should show us more of your code, so we can see how the "child" forms are creaed aswell. In fact, from your description _i cannot resize it without breaking the layout_ I'm having doubts if these "child forms" really are forms or simply **controls** on your main form.. If that is the case, have a look at the controls [Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor) property.

Comment: thanks, i realized that it would be better to start over with better choices.